# How to Strip and Separate values from column in Pandas Dataframe to int values

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I want to strip and separate values from a column to another column in Pandas dataframe. Te current values are like

```
df['column']

14.535.00
14.535.00
14.535.00
```

I want to remove the 00 after second dot(.) and store them in another column
df['new_column'] as int values so that I could perform arithmetic operations

Answer (score 1):

Edit 1:  Seems like apply is always bad, seems like a more accepted solution is to use list comprehensions.

```
df['new_column'] = [str(x).split('.')[-1] for x in df.iloc[:,0]]
```

DON'T DO WHAT'S BELOW

I think this is a good instance for using apply.  You might not need the *str* call.

What this is doing is taking the values in your column (aka a Series) and applying a function to them.  The function takes each item, makes it a string, splits on the period, and grabs the last value.  We then store the results of all this into a new column.

```
df['new_column'] = df['column'].iloc[:,0].apply(lambda x: str(x).split('.')[-1])
```

should result in something like what you want

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54432583/when-should-i-ever-want-to-use-pandas-apply-in-my-code

Comment: thanks!  I'm not familiar with how to do this without apply, but it sounds like there should be a way?

Comment: Since this is string data, you can look at some of the list comprehension examples under the "String/Regex" subheading.

Comment: This is not working, seems more like it is taking data from other columns as I am getting complete unexpected output.

Comment: @AbhinavKumar did you replace the 0 with the preppier column index?

Comment: I did -   df['new_column'] = [str(x).split('.')[-1] for x in df.iloc[:,'old_column']]
Errors

Comment: so you've wrapped what I gave you in '[]' which I'm not sure if that would be good or bad.  But otherwise it should work just fine.  What is your error?

Comment: ignore my comment about the '[]' wasn't thinking